# how to use $wpdb variable in separate file

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like writing custom queries in WordPress in separate file php.

my class :

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        //$this->db = new DB_Connect();
       // $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    //------------------------------------------------


    function test(){
        global $wpdb;
        $q = "SELECT
                  wp_posts.ID as ID
                FROM
                  wp_posts
                WHERE 1 = 1
                  AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%s%'
                  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
                  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
                ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
                LIMIT 0, 5 ";

       $arr = $wpdb->get_results($q);

       foreach($arr as $a ){
           echo $a['ID'];
       }
    }

}

?>
```

But `test` function does not return(echo) anything.
Where is my wrong ?

**updated**

returning of `var_dump` of `$arr`:

```
> array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5354 (1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "6533"
> } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5353 (1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "5838" } [2]=>
> object(stdClass)#5352 (1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "5786" } [3]=>
> object(stdClass)#5351 (1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "5282" } [4]=>
> object(stdClass)#5350 (1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "5230" } }
```

**solved:**

```
   foreach($arr as $a ){
       echo $a->ID;
   }
```

Comment: Any error message? What about a `var_dump` of `$arr`?

Comment: @ vard updated, added return values.

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code :

```
<?php
require '../../../wp-load.php';

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    function test(){
        global $wpdb;
        $q = "SELECT
                  wp_posts.ID as ID
                FROM
                  wp_posts
                WHERE 1 = 1
                  AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%s%'
                  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
                  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
                ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
                LIMIT 0, 5 ";

       $arr = $wpdb->get_results($q);

       foreach($arr as $a ){
           echo $a['ID'];
       }
    }

}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to get wordpress configuration and database object is `wp-load.php`. so include this file inside your class and then you can use `$wpdb` object like this

```
require '../../../wp-load.php';    //change this path according to file
class DB_Functions {
   public function init()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('');

}
}
```